# How to get width of GestureDetector in flutter?

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector

I'm doing a web-app and it looks like this:
[Image of the web app for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ab9bD.png), where you can choose how hot your water should be (just a silly example to illustrate my problem).

the code to that looks like the following:

```
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
            onTapDown: (val) {
              print(val.localPosition.dx);
            },
            child: Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.red])),
              height: 100,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            )),
      ),
    );
```

I'm trying to detect how fare from the left edge the user has pressed the gesture Detector. I add a print statement and it tells me the number of pixels.

But what i need is something like a percentage, for example when the user presses the Container in the middle it should return 50% or 0.5 or something like that. Just the numbers of pixels doesnt help me to further set the temperature. Since the width of the container is changing by the window size, I can not simply divide the dx value of the positoin by the width of the container.

Any ideas how to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put everything in a new widget and use the build context of the build method:

```
class Thermometer extends StatelessWidget {
  const Thermometer({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        onTapDown: (x) {
          print(context.size?.width);
          print("--> ${100 * x.localPosition.dx / (context.size?.width ?? 1)}%");
        },
        child: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.red])),
          height: 100,
        ));
  }
}
```

That prints something like

```
779.111083984375

--> 20.764405690078366%
```

when you tap on it.

Answer (score 0):

For me, if you want to create a beautiful UI relates to "choose value between x & y", you should use [slider](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Slider-class.html) instead of `GestureDetector` - much easier. If you want to get width of screen, use `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width`, the size of `GestureDetector` is also the size of it child (well, imagine you remove `GestureDetector`, what is that `Container` size). If you have padding, take the screen width minus the padding...

Comment: yes, thats a good idea with the subtraction, but the example above is just for illustation purpose - in my real application, the position of the Container is not so easy to calculate since it is surrounded by some more widgets and in an Expand widget. 

Also I dont really like the appearance of the Slider-widget. Thats why I dont want to use a Slider. But you are right, it would be much easier.

Comment: try to use RenderBox: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68152970/how-to-get-size-of-a-child-widget  -> to get width of child Container

Comment: I cant use the code in the answer to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68152970/how-to-get-size-of-a-child-widget), it says "A  value of type 'RenderObject?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'RenderBox'". Probably something with the new Dart version? I'm not sure..

Comment: try `key.currentContext!.findRenderObject()! as RenderBox;`

Comment: Thank you for your help, but now it says "The getter 'size' isn't defined for the type 'RenderObject'." to the code line `final sizeRed = renderBoxRed!.size;`. I was not able to figure out any field of RenderObject that holds the widgets width. Any suggestions for that?